# Custom NIO filesystem doesn't load through SBT's test task

Tags: scala, sbt, nio2

For testing, I'm using an in-memory NIO `FileSystem` implementaion ( [memoryfs](https://github.com/openCage/memoryfs) ). I've taken advantage of it before, and it seems to run fine through e.g. Maven.

However, now, **in an SBT project, it's impossible to initialize a new `FileSystem`**.

Here's a minimal SBT configuration to reproduce the problem:

```scala
import sbt._
import Keys._

name := "testfs"
organization := "com.example
version := "0.1-SNAPSHOT"

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

libraryDependencies ++= { 
  val scalaTestVersion = "2.2.5"
  Seq(
    "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % scalaTestVersion % "test",
    "org.mockito" %  "mockito-core" % "1.10.19" % "test",
    "de.pfabulist.lindwurm" %  "memoryfs" % "0.28.3"   % "test"
  )}
```

And here's a test:

```scala
import de.pfabulist.lindwurm.memory.MemoryFSBuilder
import org.scalatest.{FlatSpec, MustMatchers}


class FsDummySpec extends FlatSpec with MustMatchers {

  it must "init the FS" in {
    new MemoryFSBuilder().watchService(true).name("testFs").build() //init here
  }
}
```

Running `sbt test` will result in:

```
[info] FsDummySpec:
[info] - must init the FS *** FAILED ***
[info]   java.nio.file.ProviderNotFoundException: Provider "memoryfs" not found
[info]   at java.nio.file.FileSystems.getFileSystem(FileSystems.java:224)
[info]   at de.pfabulist.kleinod.paths.Pathss.getOrCreate(Pathss.java:76)
```

Here's the thing: **this should run without any problems**. My question is: **why, and how to fix it**?

Glancing over the [custom FS provider docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/filesystemprovider.html) it looks like SBT borks the classpath somehow, but its hard to say why.

*Note:* interestingly enough, IntelliJ IDEA's test runner seems to work without a hitch, the problem is only on the command line (in "SBT proper").

Comment: java uses the file "META-INF/services/java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider" to locate FileSystemProviders. If you have more than one custom FileSystem you might have merge problem. To check whether it is a problem with memoryfs try using one of the other decent in-memory filesystems, e.g. JimFS.
P.S. as author of memoryfs I am happy to hear from a user and really interested in the outcome .

Comment: @openCage : wow, thank you for the interest in this question! Your comment decidedly helped, see the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment by openCage hinted at the solution.

It turns out custom file systems do require an additional element, i.e. a service provider definition file located in `META-INF/services`.

**If you use a custom NIO FileSystem, you need to make that provider definition file available in the test classpath.**

The simplest way is probably just to fork the test VM, i.e. add the following to your `build.sbt`:

```scala
fork in Test := true
```